# Matching torque SI units from two different formula

Tags: classical-mechanics

Torque = r x F = r*F*sin(theta) => So units will be kg*m^2/s^2

Torque = I*alpha => SI units is kg*m^2*rad/s^2

There is a rad unit extra in the second formula. They both should match right because they are calculating torque.

Comment: Radian is essentially dimensionless.

Comment: A simpler quantity with this same (non-)issue is speed. In uniform circular motion, $v=r\omega$.

Comment: The output of the sine function is unitless, not radians.

Answer (score 4):

Rad or radians has no physical dimensions and so both these equations are correct.